# I want to retrieve all the publications lists that it's inside of a folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

I have this code that retrieve all publications lists (Id and Name) from marketing cloud

I would like to retrieve just publications lists that it's inside of my folder called "Morning Message"

Follow my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var allPublicationLists = getAllPublicationLists();

    for (var i in allPublicationLists) {
        Write("\n" + allPublicationLists[i]["ID"] + "|"  +allPublicationLists[i]["Name"]);
    }    

    function getAllPublicationLists() {

        var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "Publication");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "QueryAllAccounts", "True");

        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ID");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
        

        var reqParams = [0,0];
        var publications = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, reqParams);

        return publications;
    }    
</script>
```

I would like to know as well, if it's possible to get this Name and Id and put inside of a table in my web page

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll need to add a filter to your RetrieveRequest and specify the categoryID of your folder.

Comment: Alright! Where can I discovery what's my CategoryID? thanks !

Comment: Hover over the folder name in the platform -- it'll be at the bottom of your browser in the URL.

Comment: Hi, I made a filter like this

var filter = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "Property", "CategoryID");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "SimpleOperator", "equal");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter, "Value", "XXXX");

I just don't know where is the right place to put it, thanks again!